# Let's get critical: Sep 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Russian Language Stack Exchange](http://russian.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://russian.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Meaning of "Мели, Емеля, твоя неделя"](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/7054/meaning-of-%d0%9c%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%95%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Difference between угрожать и грозить](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/7149/difference-between-%d1%83%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8-%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- ["cutoff" in an integral](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/7059/cutoff-in-an-integral)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Meaning of "Предельный"](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/7067/meaning-of-%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Use of the perfective with постепенно](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/7141/use-of-the-perfective-with-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [uncertainty about some uses of motion verbs](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/7099/uncertainty-about-some-uses-of-motion-verbs)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [What is the difference between одолеть and преодолеть?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/7029/what-is-the-difference-between-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%8c-and-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%8c)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Is склока in current Russian usage?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/7105/is-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0-in-current-russian-usage)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Which of the open source speech synthesizers is the best for Russian Language?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/7042/which-of-the-open-source-speech-synthesizers-is-the-best-for-russian-language)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Androgenic hair по-русски](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/7035/androgenic-hair-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8)

**Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 3)

---